# What’s the difference between Array<T>, ContiguousArray<T>, and ArraySlice<T> in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

In Swift 2, what is the major difference between the three array variants:

- Array
- ContiguousArray
- ArraySlice

Can anyone explain this with a real world example?

Comment: check http://ankit.im/swift/2016/01/08/exploring-swift-array-implementation/ for details

Comment: @user3441734 link is dead

Comment: @J.Doe updated http://ankit.im/swift/2016/01/07/exploring-swift-array-implementation/ it is old, but still usable informations there

Comment: @user3441734 wow that is master swift stuff 0__0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](http://swiftdoc.org/):

**ContiguousArray:**

> Efficiency is equivalent to that of Array, unless T is a class or @objc protocol type, in which case using ContiguousArray may be more efficient. Note, however, that ContiguousArray does not bridge to Objective-C. See Array, with which ContiguousArray shares most properties, for more detail.

Basically, whenever you would store **classes** or **@objc protocol** types in an array, you might want to consider using `ContiguousArray` instead of an `Array`.

**ArraySlice**

> ArraySlice always uses contiguous storage and does not bridge to Objective-C.
>
> Warning: Long-term storage of ArraySlice instances is discouraged
>
> Because a ArraySlice presents a view onto the storage of some larger
>   array even after the original array's lifetime ends, storing the slice
>   may prolong the lifetime of elements that are no longer accessible,
>   which can manifest as apparent memory and object leakage. To prevent
>   this effect, use ArraySlice only for transient computation.

ArraySlices are used most of the times when you want to get a subrange from an Array, like:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let slice = numbers[Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 2)] //[1, 2]
```

Any other cases you should use `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

Good source on different class of Swift is : http://swiftdoc.org/

Array is very clear so lets talk about other two.

ContiguousArray: http://swiftdoc.org/type/ContiguousArray/

> A fast, contiguously-stored array of T.
>
> Efficiency is equivalent to that of Array, unless T is a class or
>   @objc protocol type, in which case using ContiguousArray may be more
>   efficient. Note, however, that ContiguousArray does not bridge to
>   Objective-C. See Array, with which ContiguousArray shares most
>   properties, for more detail.

ArraySlice : http://swiftdoc.org/type/ArraySlice/

> The Array-like type that represents a sub-sequence of any Array,
>   ContiguousArray, or other ArraySlice.
>
> ArraySlice always uses contiguous storage and does not bridge to
>   Objective-C.

In short:

ContiguousArray is for more efficiency when T is a class or @objc protocol type
ArraySlice is to represent Array in sub part.

Comment: We can cast a ArraySlice to an Array , is that possible with Contiguous array.. And how to use this and when?

Answer (score 2):

There is new doc from Apple. https://git.io/vg5uw

So,

> `ContiguousArray<Element>` is the fastest and simplest of the three—use
>   this when you need "C array" performance. The elements of a
>   ContiguousArray are always stored contiguously in memory.

.

> `Array<Element>` is like `ContiguousArray<Element>`, but optimized for
>   efficient conversions from Cocoa and back—when Element can be a class
>   type, `Array<Element>` can be backed by the (potentially non-contiguous)
>   storage of an arbitrary NSArray rather than by a Swift
>   ContiguousArray. `Array<Element>` also supports up- and downcasts
>   between arrays of related class types. When Element is known to be a
>   non-class type, the performance of `Array<Element>` is identical to that
>   of `ContiguousArray<Element>`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift defines the following classes that implement the ArrayType protocol; **Array, ContiguousArray, Slice**.

Swift Array is the main class that represents arrays, The array is a generic class that takes 1 type, An array of integers will have the type of `Array<Int>`, creating an integer array:

```
var myArray = Array<Int>()
```

Slice is an array with an internal implementation that makes removing elements from the top of the array computationally cheap. The following will perform good on a Slice type:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr[1…4]
```

There is not much documentation regarding the ContiguousArray, but from its name one can guess that it has to do with the internal array storage, probably the elements are stored in Contiguous Memory Allocation layout.

[Read more.](https://medium.com/@NSomar/swift-collections-1b271764d79)

Answer (score 1):

## Slices Maintain Indices

This isn't a complete answer. But something with a litte gothcha from Swift:

```
let array = [1,4,9,12,15]
```

Do you think the value of the following would be same?

```
print(array[2..<5].index(of:12)) // is it 1 or 3?
print(array.index(of:12)) // 3
```

Yes! for both it would print `3`. This is because the ArraySlice will not get its own unique copy (unless the Array is mutated). ArraySlice is basically a way to look into certain indexes of the same Array. It won't create a new array of [9,12,15] and look into it. It would just look into the *given range* of the *original* Array.

Now how about this? Do you think the value of the following would be same?

```
print(array[2..<5].index(of:1)) // nil
print(array.index(of:1)) // 0
```

No! The ArraySlice will print `nil`, while the Array will print `0`

And obviously:

```
print(array[2..<4][2]) // 9
print(array[2..<4][0]) // ERROR: out of bounds
```

And again surprisingly:

```
print(array.dropFirst(2).index(of:15)
```

is **not** `2`. It's would return `4` as its Index. Why? Because [dropFirst](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688121-dropfirst) returns an `ArraySlice`. If you don't want it to maintain indexes then you should construct a new Array out of the ArraySlice...

**EDIT:**

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice):

> Unlike Array and ContiguousArray, **the starting index for an ArraySlice
>   instance isn’t always zero**. Slices maintain the same indices of the
>   larger array for the same elements, so the starting index of a slice
>   depends on how it was created, letting you perform index-based
>   operations on either a full array or a slice.

<sub>If you were interested for more. The link to the docs also has another example</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that Swift designers are creating something that is not really useful. The ArraySlice paradigm makes it very difficult to step across an encoded string value and extract individual pieces without having a "starting" index so you end up with code, in a function that is passed a slice, with having to create your own index value, starting at the starting index of the slice and then stepping forward through the slice with expressions and notions that are unfamiliar to people used to other languages and other array or set data structures.

Parsing a string and getting characters out of it and computing things with ascii numeric values for characters becomes very difficult.