# The ContiguousArray's internal structure

Tags: arrays, swift

I know there are some related question about the difference between `Array` and `ContiguousArray`.

However, the answers focus on how to use them, not themself.

In the official documentation, they say

> The ContiguousArray type is a specialized array that always stores its elements in a contiguous region of memory. This contrasts with Array, which can store its elements in either a contiguous region of memory or an NSArray instance if its Element type is a class or @objc protocol.

So, in `Array` the element may be in a contiguous region or an `NSArray` instance if the element is a class or @objc protocol. I thought the `Array` has just pointers of objects. So, I don't understand the meaning of **a contiguous region**.

And how is `NSArray` related of `Array`?  Is `Array` just a wrapper of `NSArray`?

Could anyone explain?

EDIT:
I had some confusions about it when I posted the question.
Presumably `ContiguousArray` has no pointer? Because the document say `ContiguousArray` always stores its elements in a contiguous region.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290576/what-s-the-difference-between-arrayt-contiguousarrayt-and-arrayslicet-in

Comment: @adev Yes, it is related, but there are no answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` and `ContiguousArray` themselves don't have reference semantics. If you store instances of a value type in either, your array's elements are properly copies of the original instances. Whether pointers are sometimes used "under the hood" for the sake of optimization (or bridging to Objective-C) is just an implementation detail, not part of the intended programming model and therefore not something you should ordinarily have to reason about.

But when low-level performance *is* a concern, `ContiguousArray` is there to guarantee that elements are laid out in memory contiguously, like a C array. A regular `Array` instance provides the same optimizations when possible (when its elements are enumerations or structures). In other cases, it can indeed behave as just a wrapper around `NSArray`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand almost.   Whether an element of `ContiguousArray` is  a reference type or a value type, `ContiguousArray` stores elements in contiguous region.  So, can I say all instances in `ContiguouArray` exist in a stack area?

Comment: In general, reference-type elements still use heap allocation, even in a contiguous array, but value-type elements are allocated on the stack. That's what enables the conditional performance increases for `Array` described above, and why they're restricted to arrays of enumerations or structures. Having said that, performance optimizations can sometimes violate these rules. You can at least expect the *performance characteristics* of stack allocation anywhere you're only using value types.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused again.  Whether we use `ContiguousArray` or `Array`, if we store instances of a class, the instances are allocated to heap area?  So, what do you mean by "a contiguous memory area"?  Both `ContiguousArray` and `Array` store pointers of instances of a class?  However, although this is just my assumption, in case of `ContiguousArray` all instances are stored in a contiguous area in heap. On other hand, in case of `Array` each instances are stored in separate areas in heap.  Am I right?

Comment: Allocation is dependent on the element type, it doesn't change depending on the collection it's contained in. Following this, dynamically allocated storage for classes and other reference types is not (and can't be) stored inline in the buffer managed by a contiguous array, or any other collection. So you're right, only the *pointers* to the dynamically allocated storage (instances on the heap) are stored contiguously inline (on the stack). Since the size of instances stored on the heap can change arbitrarily at run time, though, there's no guarantee of contiguous layout there.

Comment: So, what exactly is the difference?  Both `ContiguousArray` and `Array` contains elements in a contiguous region on the stack in case of a value type object. On the other hand, for a reference type both `ContiguousArray` and `Array` contains pointers contiguously and the pointers indicate instances on the heap.  So, there seems to be no difference. Could you explain?

Comment: I guess my last comment was a bit ambiguous—only `ContiguousArray` *guarantees* contiguous layout (on the stack, whether the inline data consists of values or pointers). `NSArray` doesn't guarantee this, so for at least this reason, `Array` can't *guarantee* it either. Under the conditions described above, `Array` behaves like `ContiguousArray`—just not under *all* conditions.

Comment: You should use `ContiguousArray` to document when contiguous layout is required for your implementation logic, and to allow the static analyzer to enforce the constraints associated with its use. At other times, I recommend just using a regular `Array`, since performance will still be optimized when possible.

Comment: Sorry for my persisting comments. To sum up, `Array` surely contains elements contiguously in case of a value type although it might contain reference type elements in not contiguous way.  However, if I use `ContiguousArray`, it always contains elements contiguously in the stack whether the elements are value type or reference type.   Is this right?

Comment: Yes, as I understand it that's all correct. And no need for apologies—as Swift's low-level capabilities are expanded over time, I expect more and more people will take an interest in this stuff. Hopefully our conversation will be useful to some of them. 

Comment: Thanks. So, when does `Array` contain elements contiguously in case the element is a reference type(pointer)?   Do you know the condition that make `Array`'s structure change?

Comment: No, I don't… Looking at the documentation, it doesn't appear that the conditions are described, which also suggests they could be changed in the future without warning. So if that would affect your app's implementation logic, you have another reason to use `ContiguousArray`.